# Web3JS: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: "" When creating new contract

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, json-rpc

I am simplying trying to create a new contract on the testnet. I am using IFURA as a node and here is my code:

```
var createInvoice = function(){
    unlockAccountsIfNeeded();
    fs.readFile('./ethereum/contracts/invoice.sol', 'utf8', function(err, contractCode) {
        if(err) console.log("error: " + err);
        var contractCompiled = solc.compile(contractCode, 1); // 1 activates the optimiser
        for (var contractName in contractCompiled.contracts) {
            var greeterContract = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(contractCompiled.contracts[contractName].interface));
            greeterContract.new({from:wallet, data: contractCompiled.contracts[contractName].bytecode, gas: 1000000}, function(e, contract){
                if(!e) {
                    if(!contract.address) {
                        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
                    } else {
                        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
                        console.log(contract);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("web3js error: " + e);
                }
            })
        }
    });
};
```

I keep getting the same error:

```
web3js error: Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
```

I am not sure what could cause the error, it seems like my code works but the parameters that I parse to greeterContract.new are not correct but I am not sure which one.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That error usually is caused by the node not accepting your commands. I'd check if your connection to infura is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that I could simply not access my IFURA Node, I changed it to a localhost node and it worked fine.

Comment: Adding my INFURA key to a secret file also worked for me.